# Why QT Creator Preview so different from what I actually get?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt-creator

New to QT, started about a month ago.

I was told that I can use setStyle() to modify the style, but windows only accept fusion and windows.

How can i get ui like preview?

Using qt5.11 , c++. Project run on windows.
If u know about these, please tell me, thanks.

This is preview

[image]

This is what I get

[image]

Comment: use `a->setStyle("fusion");`

Comment: tried but still can't make buttons like preview

Comment: Are you executing that code in Qt Creator or directly the executable? If you are doing the second thing, have you used windeployqt?

Comment: Qt tries to make your application look like a native application. This means that, sans custom styling, you shouldn't really worry how your program looks in a given platform: It's up to the user to decide how his system looks like, and all native apps should oblige.